# What does it mean transport in network program

Tags: meaning, word-usage

All, I just read the book `Netty in action`. A word `Transport` is mentioned in the book like below.

> ```
> NIO is used in this example because it’s currently the most widely used transport,
> thanks to its scalability and thoroughgoing asynchrony. But a different transport
> implementation could be used as well. If you wished to use the OIO transport in your
> server, you’d specify OioServerSocketChannel and OioEventLoopGroup. We’ll explore
> transports in greater detail in chapter 4.
> ```

What does it mean the `Transport`? Thanks.

Comment: Probably future questions of this nature would be better addressed in one of the computer-related StackExchange groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this very technical context, the transport refers to a method and protocol for sending data over a network from one machine to another.  It is a layer in the communication stack well described [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer).